# How to stop by Webform from sending duplicate emails?

Tags: webforms, emails

So I have a webform in Drupal 7 that is set up like this:
[image: My webform testing field picture]

And I made it so that each of those checkboxes can share the same email key.  But when I submit my form, it will send duplicate emails to that address depending on how many boxes I checked.  How can I make it so that when I check multiple boxes, it will send only one email to that address they share?

Comment: When you say "email key" does that mean that the value for each of those checkboxes is an actual email address? If so then it would show up in the html which you probably don't want to expose to spammers.